# What does double INF mean in PHP warning?

Tags: php, json, warnings

I have been getting this PHP Warning:

> json_encode(): double INF does not conform to the JSON spec, encoded
>   as 0 in /var/www/html/search.php on line 167

Line 167 in search.php file contains this:

```
json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

What does **double INF** mean?

Comment: For posterity, with my build of PHP, I can trigger this error with `json_encode(1.79e308*1000)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Double can mean http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format
- INF means infinity
- JSON can't store numbers with value infinity: http://www.json.org/

What was the data you were trying to encode?

Comment: I see. Thanks for your quick answer. Now I know where is my problem. Thanks a lot!